Changing BIOS from PEG to IGD made it impossible to enter BIOS
I have a CPU Intel 10400. It has integrated graphics.
I've been using that iGPU for years, with two monitors plugged into motherboard (using HDMI-HDMI and VGA-HDMI cables) until I recently bought RX 570 Sapphire Nitro+ 8gb.
It turned out that no matter in which ports of the GPU I plug my three monitors, only two would work at the same time. So I decided to plug two monitors into the GPU (using DP cables) and one monitor into motherboard (tried HDMI and VGA cables).
It didn't work - at first. Then I went to BIOS, kept the PEG option there, but turned on the multi-display option. Once that was done, the third monitor started to work, with only drawback of blinking into blackness once a minute or so.
To fix that I decided to try to change PEG to IGD in BIOS. My understanding was that it would use iGPU during the boot process. However after the change I can't see my BIOS - all monitors are black until the OS boots.
I tried to take out the motherboard's (MSI B460M-A PRO) battery and putting it back 15 minutes later, however it didn't help - I still can't see BIOS.
I'm at my wits' end. Now I wouldn't even be able to reinstall my OS, because I can't change the boot order in BIOS, because I can't see BIOS.
EDIT:
After I took out and put back the motherboard's battery, I also tried to take out the GPU. The BIOS can't be seen, but two monitors plugged into motherboard work as normal.
If GPU is plugged in, the BIOS can't be seen, and only monitors plugged into the GPU work, those plugged into the motherboard don't work.

Have you tried removing the RX 570?

@Mokubai Please see edit

This item on reddit seems to say that you might be able to use 2xHDMI + 1xDP, in case that's a combination you didn't try.

Have you pressed the key to go into the BIOS even though you can't see the initial screen? It's possible it's set to fast boot so you don't get to see it. Referring to the manual, page 17 states how the BIOS should be reset, and page 19 implies that there can be a problem using an older graphics card. The latter led me to rx570 gop issue - do you know if your RX570 has had its VBIOS updated?

@AndrewMorton Thank you for the answer, I managed to clear the motherboard memory, changed setting to PEG, now somehow all three monitors work (2 in motherboard, 1 in GPU), with no blinking!

Couple things:

Try using these procedures from your manual to clear the CMOS (just removing the battery would not clear CMOS on a modern MB)


Try using a raw VGA cable and monitor (not a digital monitor). I've seen it before where the digital graphics won't load fast enough with certain MB settings. IGD means INTEGRATED ONLY - so only the connections that do directly into the MB are going to work. This VGA connection (don't use the HDMI):



Lastly to address your monitor concern. You may be running into a HDMI/DP signal typing issue. What I would try is plugging in 2 monitors with the HDMI cable, and the third using the DVI cable. Get a DVI to HDMI converter, DVI usually converts well from HDMI.

Do you happen to know that 2xHDMI + DVI can work? The thread I linked to in an earlier comment seems to say that combination is almost guaranteed to fail.

Thank you. I shorted the JBAT1 and managed to enter BIOS! The default value is PEG (even though I have the GPU removed right now), so I left it at PEG

Also my motherboard only has one HDMI, and zero Display Ports (it has HDMI and VGA)

With PEG and multi monitor being ON, and with an inserted GPU (no monitors connected to GPU, two monitors connected to motherboard), the two monitors don't turn on

When I disconnect PCI cables from GPU, but keep it insert (all two monitors are in motherboard), the monitors turn on when OS loads, but can't display BIOS

With GPU removed, PEG and multi monitor ON in BIOS, I can see OS, but not BIOS

So I shorted JBAT1 again, managed to enter BIOS (GPU is removed). I enabled IGD Multi-Monitor again. OS loads fine on monitors, I shut down and turned the PC back on, I can enter BIOS just fine (GPU is still removed, multi monitor is enabled)

I inserted GPU, but did not connect PCI cables to it. BIOS loads fine on monitors, (monitors are in motherboard)

I connected PCI cables to GPU. Then I turned on the PC, it briefly turned off (it always happens when I connect GPU for the very first time), then turned itself on again. I can't see BIOS on monitors, not can I see OS

Now if I connect a third monitor to the GPU (to DP port), I can see OS on the third monitor, but the first two (connected to motherboard) are black at first, but after a reboot they turn on after I enter OS

With the third monitor connected I can see BIOS on it.

And where I wrote VGA I meant DVI, sorry got them confused

Now I have two monitors plugged into motherboard (HDMI and DVI), and the third monitor is plugged into the GPU (DisplayPort). All three now work. Thank you!

@parsecer HAHA sorry, I was out of town this weekend. I'm glad you were able to get them all connected.

@parsecer Just keep in mind that only that one monitor you have in the GPU will benefit from its' performance. You should be able to use 2 HDMI and 1x DVI (all on the GPU)
